# Web server: how to allow users to browse into compressed files?

Tags: apache, webserver

I'm looking for an Apache configuration, module, or perhaps cgi/php/whatever script to allow users of my website to not only browse directories but also browse right into compressed .zip files (*) in those directories as if they were regular directories.

Background:

I run an Apache web server and one of the services it provides is a simple directory listing to some files that people need access to.

Some of these files are compressed (*) and generally that is good because people normally want to download the whole thing. However it would be really useful if it were also possible to seamlessly browse into the compressed files just as if they were regular folders.

While I could write a cgi script to do this myself, surely this has been done before. Surely, although my web searches have not found one, there's just an Apache module to do it.

Any pointers?

Steve

(*) Using .zip, not .tar.bz2, alas. It's a requirement, don't blame me.